# Laravel 6 | Confirm alert usando SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert

estoy tratando de crear un alert de confirmación al eliminar una categoría de la base de datos y no puedo.

¿Cómo debería ser el  para que salte el alert de confirmación?

Este es el formulario

```html
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['admin.categories.destroy', $category->id], 'method'=> 'DELETE'])!!}

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Eliminar</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Hice el include del js en la vista

```
@include('sweetalert::alert')
```

Y este es el controlador

```php
public function destroy($id){

Category::find($id)->delete();

return back()->with('info', 'Se eliminó la categoría <strong>' . $category->name . </strong> correctamente');
}
```

Este es el script de la documentacion oficial

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que no funciona?

Comment: no se como debería ser el script utilizando sweetalert para lanzar el alert de confirmacion al darle al boton eliminar,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que Sweetalert funciona en el lado del cliente, debes llamar algún código de Javascript que haga la solicitud al servidor para que se elimine dicho registro de las bases de datos, teniendo en cuenta la seguridad en dicha petición HTTP:

1. Debes capturar el clic que va a activar el popup de confirmación de Sweetalert, algo así:

   ```
   <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="confirmDelete">Eliminar</button>
   ```
2. En dicha función, llamas a SweetAlert:

   ```
   function confirmDelete(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     Swal.fire({
       title: '¿Está seguro?',
       icon: 'warning',
       showCancelButton: true,
       confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
       cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
       confirmButtonText: 'Sí'
     }).then((result) => {
       if (result.value) {
         // Al confirmar que se desea eliminar
         deleteRequest();
       }
     })
   }
   ```
3. Por último, envias la información al servidor, desde Javascript:

   ```
   function deleteRequest() {
     // enviar información al servidor, vía ajax, o por algún otro método
   }
   ```

NOTA: lo único que te resta por hacer, es determinar como pasas el id o los parámetros necesarios del registro que deseas eliminar.